# Uso de archivos JSON con Java

Tags: json

Disculpen el atrevimiento por pedir ayuda pero soy nuevo en el mundo de la programacion. estoy trabajando con java y tengo un problema al leer archivos JSON.

el programa tiene que leer varios archivos JSON en una carpeta y regresar el resultado de la busqueda de cada archivo por cada linea.

Estoy atorado ya vi como leer el archivo pero solo puedo hacerlo uno a la vez y no toda la carpeta.

Me sale el nombre del archivo json pero me sale Null para determinado valor del JSON

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.*;

public class SimpleTesting {

    public static void findAllFilesInFolder(File folder) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException,ParseException {
        for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
                    
            if (!file.isDirectory()) {
                            
                System.out.println(file.getName());
                                JSONParser parser= new JSONParser();
                                try{
                                    Object obj= parser.parse(new FileReader(file));
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
                                    System.out.println("JSON LEIDO"+jsonObject.get("estadoOperacion"));
                                    
                                  
                                }  catch(FileNotFoundException e)  {}
                                catch (IOException e){}
                                
                                  
                                
            } else {
                findAllFilesInFolder(file);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, IOException {
        File folder = new File("/Users/Downloads/numeros/aJIJIO");
        findAllFilesInFolder(folder);
    }
```

Comment: Hola segormelos, bienvenido, 
para poder ayudarte, necesitamos tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo en formato texto (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema, y de ser posible que se pueda ejecutar), y si recibes errores, indica cuales son.  

mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!.

Comment: Hola amigo gracias

Comment: Ya lo modifique saludos

Comment: ya pude sin su ayuda gracias de todas formas

Comment: NO SE QUISIERON GANAR UNOS PESOS PARA SU PASAJE

Comment: Hola de nuevo, bien que pudiste resolverlo, ahora podrías agregar tu solución como respuesta, para ayudar a otros, y tal vez, llevarte algún puntito de reputación!!!